# Determining which test statistic is better under two different scenarios

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Problem: I have 9 independent normal observations from a normal dist. with $\sigma=10$. And we want to test $H_0:\mu=150$vs $H_A:\mu\neq 150$. Also $\alpha=0.05$ which uses the test statistic $M_1=|\bar{x}-150|$ with a critical value of $6.53$ and for a second test statistic $M_2=|\bar{x}-152|$ with a critical value of $7.55$.

Under Test statistic 1 when I calculate the power of test against the alternative $\mu=151$ I get a power $1$ of $.0604$ and when the alternative is $\mu=149$ I get a power $2$ of $.0604$.

Under Test statistic 2  for the same conditions I get a power $1$ of $.0298866$ and when the alternative is $\mu=149$ I get a power $2$ of $.08698$.

Now according to this information I have to determine whats the best test. Since we do not know what the actual mean that is $\mu$ and since 150 and 152 are not that far from one another we can compare their power. Since test statistic 2 has a bigger power in both scenarios then test statistic 1 then id say that is the better test since higher power means that the chances of a type 1 error would decrease. Would this be a correct line of reasoning? Or am I forgetting to take alpha into consideration? I was thinking that Under test statistic 2 the alpha is $.023512$ which is lower than $.05$. So I think it still works out to be test stat 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\alpha$ is a *defined* quantity and specifies your chances of a Type I error.

*Power*, on the other hand, is more subjective since it depends on how wrong your null hypothesis is. Note that $power = 1-P(\text{Type II error })$.

In general, you want the test that gives you the highest power for a given $\alpha$. In many cases, the power of one test is *uniformly* higher then the power of another test, regardless of the degree to which the null hypothesis is wrong. In this case, the higher power test is called *uniformly more powerful* than the lower test.

In some cases, you can actually identify *the* uniformly *most* powerful test (UMPT). Which is obviously the ideal test when it is applicable.

You need to compare the power of Statistic 1 vs. Statistic 2 under a range of "true" values, holding $\alpha$ constant. Hopefully one will have a consistently higher power and you can choose that one.

Comment: I'll just have to graph the power functions and see which one has a higher power as I get at what your saying.

Comment: @user60887 yep...that should help you make your decision. Also,  you can form risk function from your Type I and Type Ii risks minimize the expected loss. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_decision_rule